# Как подключиться в DataGrip (Jetbrains) к зашифрованной БД с помощью нативного драйвера SQLite.Interop.dll?

Tags: sqlite3, jetbrains, datagrip

Подскажите, как подключиться к базе данных SQLite3 с помощью нативного драйвера SQLite.Interop.dll из [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) 2021.1.
Драйвер взял отсюда [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).
Распаковал скачанный архив и в качестве драйвера использую файл SQLite.Interop.dll.
Подключение пркрасно работает, если пытаюсь подключиться в других программах, сложности только с DataGrip.

Вот так выглядит окно выбора драйвера:
[image: Выбор драйвера для БД]

UPD.
При попытке использовать драйвер из коробки (Xerial SQLiteJDBC, ver.3.34.0) получаю ошибку подключения к БД, хотя сам Test Connection проходит успешно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? Как выглядит ошибка подключения?

Comment: @moscas Если удалить существующий драйвер и попытаться подключить нативный dll драйвер, то появляется сообщение 'No driver found files'.

Comment: вам нужен JDBC драйвер, файл драйвера должен называться примерно так sqlite-jdbc-3.34.0.jar.   SQLite.Interop.dll это библиотека не для java-приложений. а в чём проблема испольщовать драйвер, который мы предлагаем из коробки?

Comment: @YuriWin, при попытке использовать драйвер из коробки (Xerial SQLiteJDBC) при переходе на вкладку SCHEMAS получаю окно "Connection Error":[26] org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_NOTADB]  File opened that is not a database file (file is not a database).
[SQLITE_NOTADB]  File opened that is not a database file (file is not a database)    
Хотя Test Connection - Succeeded.   Я не понимаю, где указать пароль, чтобы подключение к БД было корректным.

Comment: @YuriWin, добавил картинки в описание.